# show notification with php when a specific data is changed in a database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, notifications

I want to notify a person a count of the jobs available in a table in my database. In a table I have a list of 8 jobs and they have their avilability. I've done the count with a PHP query with `SELECT COUNT(*) AS jobs...` and created this ajax script which shows the count with an interval.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
    setInterval(function() {
    $('#divToRefresh').load('notification.php'); //this contains the query
    }, 30000); 
    });
```

However, I am not sure how I can make it so when the user sees the notifcation alert, they will close it and it doesn't appear again until there's a new available job.

I can't find anything on the good ol google either.

Comment: What does notification.php is printing?

Comment: thats where my php query is situated. it just does a count of how many jobs there are with the "available" status

Comment: You mean `New Notifications` ? Just go through my answer once..

Comment: When user clicks close you could send another ajax request to mark the notification as read, if I understand your question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I meant new notifications @void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery function is running in 30 seconds intervals polling data from server. `notification.php` returns pre-rendered HTML containing (I assume among other things) the number of jobs available.

Check the number of available jobs and show notification based on that:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var oldNumberOfJobs = newNumberOfJobs = 0;
    $('#divToRefresh').load('notification.php'); //this contains the query
    newNumberOfJobs = $('#divWithJobsCount').text;

    if (newNumberOfJobs > oldNumberOfJobs) {
        // show notification to the user
    }

    oldNumberOfJobs = newNumberOfJobs;

}, 30000);
```

To be more specific (showing/hiding notifications), I need to see your HTML.

This solution feels bulky. The whole pre-rendered HTML is being reloaded again and again. A nicer approach would be to only return the number of jobs available and only update that number using jQuery.

Also, it might be a good idea to return the latest `job_id` as well as the total number of jobs available. This way, you could check if the latest `job_id` that is already stored in the front end matches the newly received `job_id`. And only if they don't match you would update the counter and show new notification.

### update

[Here is a jsfiddle.js](http://jsfiddle.net/jzelenkov/3L9spa30/6/) which covers your case. Jobs counter is simulated with current number of minutes. The function checks every 15 seconds if the number of minutes has changed. Once it happens, an alert notification is shown (but only if the old one was closed).

> `setInterval` in jsfiddle is written using a mock object so that it is testable in the browser without AJAX requests. In your code use the following form:
>
> ```
> setInterval(function() {
>    $.get('notification.php', checkJobsCounter); // returns jobs count in plain text
> }, 30000);
> ```

Comment: In my database i have jobid and availability so i just want to show the available count of jobs to the users as a notification when they login

Comment: @user11119483 I've updated the jsfiddle again to keep it simple. No JSON, the back end returns the number of jobs as plain text.

Comment: phew, i've just been googling how to encode my results to json cause i have no idea how you do it (never done it), i'll test it now

Comment: Do you you have a column in your table named "availability"? If so, try changing label to something else, like avail. Also use like to compare strings: "SELECT COUNT(*) as avail FROM jobs WHERE availability like '%available%'"

Comment: I've done it :) could the code be affected in any way if i change the `$.get` to `load` in interval (how i got it to wokr, and placed jobs_count so the count is displayed from php) but thanks for all your great help! could you just walk me through how it works please so i understand better. :)

Comment: $('').load replaces the contents of a selector with the response from server. $.get() executes a callback function when response is returned. This approach allows for more flexibility. I've included comments in the source code to make it more clear. The best reference is the official docs: http://api.jquery.com. Ask new specific questions about things you don't understand in jQuery/PHP/SQL. This question is getting way too bloated.

Comment: I've defined a template for a dismissible alert. It is included in the DOM in a hidden state. That template is cloned every time a new dismissible alert needed to be shown. This approach is considered better than writing HTML code to create a new dismissible alert in JavaScript.

Comment: i see, just have so many questions!! haha, you're an amazing person! thanks for everything! last quick question, how can i make it if the jobs_count = 0 not display the notification (if its possible)

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to make an `AJAX` call and the response of it should be the `number of new notifications`. Now check if `num>0` then just do `$("#notification").fadeIn();` which is a by default hidden div having text **You have new notification (or whatever)** and a close button.

```
$(doument).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get("notification.php", function(data){
            if(data>0) 
                {
                $("#div").fadeIn();
                }
        });
    },1000);
});
```

Once user closes this you can create a cookie in the browser of the user and then check if cookie is set dont make ajax request, This was you dont have to update the db and every user will be able to see the notification.

Comment: Doesn't sound hard but I have no idea how to do that :(

Comment: Thanks for your help, it doesn't seem to display the count of the currently available jobs I have. :( Basically this is what I have as an alert box right now (a simple bootstrap dismissal alert box for now). http://jsfiddle.net/1674wxhL/ How could I implement your code so it shows the count in the alert box. The php script is `echo $count[0];`. I like the idea of storing cookies so every user could see it also. Would I be able to check the cookie with jquery?